# grails design classes and external data (spreadsheet)

Tags: grails, data-structures, google-sheets-api, grails-domain-class

Having a bit of an issues on design, and was hoping I could ask for advice here. Accept that grails may be the completely wrong tool, but such is life.

So have been working away on a web app that basically just present a lot of information from a google spreadsheet and sends some updates back. I have managed to get most of it working but decided to rewrite it to get rid of my ridiculous spaggeti code as well as the many pieces of broken code that lays strewn throughout the project.

The system is relatively small, two-three users. The amount of data is small as well. One worksheets with max 500 rows (four columns) and another one with potentially 5000 (four columns). So all small, but I need it (well, want it) to stay in the google spreadsheet and the application feeding from there.

There are three classes I need for this to work, 
Google authentication class      keeps information on keys and tokens to speak to google 
Google Spreadsheet class         keeps information on the source spreadsheet
Google Data Entry                keeps information from the two spreadsheets based on a unique id

So here is my question, what should I define these classes as. Thought I would use Domain classes, but then realised that these are stored in a database. Is there a way of keeping domain classes session dependent, I.E., that two users can use the same app on the same server but never see each others data and that the data is destroyed on logout. If not, is there some other class I can use that works similar to Domain class but kept in memory user/session specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what exactly your requirements for those classes, but here are some thoughts anyway.

First, you may want to ask if they can't just be "normal" classes in `src/groovy`. I say "normal" here in the sense that they may just encapsulate some data and behavior, and you are responsible to create instances of them and call the methods appropriately when needed.

But, if you want to tie some data and behavior to the user session (as you seem to, because you asked for *session dependent domain classes*), you may want to use a [Grails Service with session scope](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Services/scope.html). When you do that, Grails will use a different instance of the service for each session of your application, and reuse the same instance for the same session until it ends.

You may also use a bit of each thing, using one service with session scope and have other classes representing the data that you pass around from the controllers to the service and vice-versa. These could actually be [Command Objects](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#commandObjects) if you needed validation and data binding, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much elias, would have voted it as useful, but don't have enough reputation to do that kind of stuff yet. Think I'll take your advice and use session scope for the actual data, as I want to keep the traffic between the app and google down a bit, then use regular classes for the rest. That should work OK, might be a bit tricky to make a smooth callback function, but hey, sometimes the spagetti belongs in your app.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it was useful. Yeah, it may take some work to glue the bits, but if it works well, hey, spaghetti it is! =)